# Analysis of Algorithms - Mathematical Model

Tags: java, algorithm, math, time-complexity

I'm doing some self study for algorithms and I can't figure out why the if statement in `ThreeSum.count()` is executed precisely `N(N-1)(N-2)/6` times?  I get that `N` refers the first for loop and so on but where does the 6 come in? Sorry if this is a really simple question.

```
public static int count(int[] a)
{ // Count triples that sum to 0.
    int N = a.length;
    int cnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
          for (int k = j+1; k < N; k++)
             if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0)
                 cnt++;
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: that `cnt++;` is part of the `if` statement not the first `for` loop.

Comment: what is for integer array `a`?

Comment: read this exact same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915495/nested-loops-into-mathematical-model-to-count-number-of-operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three `for` loops enumerate all possibilities to select 3 elements out of N. Therefore the `if` will be executed <sup>N</sup> C <sub>3</sub> times which can be calculated as `N(N-1)(N-2)/(3 . 2 . 1)`.

See for example [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) for the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Let's build it bottom up.
The most inner loop repeats itself `j` times for each `j`.

So, it actually repeats itself `sum(j | j=0,...,i-1)`

[We know that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) `sum(j | j=0,...,i-1) = i(i-1)/2 = [i^2-i]/2`

And `i` repeat itself `n` times, so we get:

```
sum(i^2-i| i=0,...,n-1)/2 = [sum(i^2) - sum(i)]/2 = [n^3/3 - n^2/2 +n/6 - n^2/2 +n/2]/2
= n^3/6 -n^2/2 +4n/12 = (n^3 - 3n^2 +2n)/6
```

But we also [know](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%28n-1%29%28n-2%29) that

```
n(n-1)(n-2) =n^3-3n^2 +2n
```

QED

---

We used in here formulas for:

1. sum(i) - [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)
2. sum(i^2) - [sum of squares](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%5E2%20%2b%201%5E2%20%2b%20%202%5E2%20%2b%20..%20%2b%20%28n-1%29%5E2)
3. n(n-1)(n-2) - binom

Answer (score 0):

A good way to figure it out is the following:
As long as there are 3 nested loops with no more than n iterations the degree of a polynomial is not higher than 3. Let's assume that it looks like
 A * x^3 + B * x^2 + C * x + D. Onecan compute it's value in 4 arbitrary points(let's say N = 0, 1, 2, 3)and solve the system of linear equations to find its coefficients.